# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'operation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function that returns the mean, median, standard deviation, max and min values of a dataset.

Below is my code: it should iterate through every item in the "ops" array and pass them into the "statSummary" function.

The function initalises a list as the operation type (e.g mean/median), performs the operation (calculates mean) and prints the result.

```
def statSummary(dataset,operation):
    operation = []
    operation.append(df[dataset].operation())

    return print(operation)

#load dataset 
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

columnNames = list(df.columns)

ops = ["mean","median","std","max","min"]

for i in ops:
    statSummary(columnNames,i)
```

However when trying to run this I recieve the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8416/4291564190.py in <module>
     30 
     31 for i in ops:
---> 32     statSummary(columnNames,i)
     33 
     34 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8416/4291564190.py in statSummary(dataset, operation)
     18 def statSummary(dataset,operation):
     19     operation = []
---> 20     operation.append(df[dataset].operation())
     21 
     22     return print(operation)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'operation'
```

The error seems to be due to ".operation())" on this line

```
operation.append(df[dataset].operation())
```

I want to 'plug' the operation variable into this line so I can iterate through my 'ops' list using "'mean','median',std'" etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `getattr`.

```
def statSummary(dataset, operation):
    func = getattr(df[dataset], operation)
    return func()  # if `operation` is `"sum"`, this is equivalent to `df[dataset].sum()`.
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out these things you can simply use df.describe().
Or you can use apply filter method using numpy. I have given sample example of this. Else you can use getattr as answered by @AKX

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one':np.array([1,2,3,4,5]),
    'two':np.array([2,4,6,8,10]),
})

def statSummary(dataset,ops):
    operation = []
    operation.append(df[dataset].apply(ops))
    return print(operation)

columnNames = list(df.columns)

ops = [np.mean,np.median,np.std,np.max,np.min]

for i in ops:
    statSummary(columnNames,i)
```